# Html input tag canot recognize corel draw and Autocad files extensions?

Tags: html, web-deployment-project

I am trying to store .dwg files to firestore but file input element can't recognize the  file type which is autocad and its extension. I want to set policy on files to upload limite extension.
how could I handle this?

we can acces file type when we open a file through   e.target.files[0].type.
If I use the extension through its name, some one can  change a vedio extension to .dwg, uploading such file is a big bug.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.